# Rancher custom template version not seen during stack upgrade

Tags: docker, rancher

I am trying to manage a custom template with several versions, but rancher detects them in wrong order (or not detects them at all):

I have 4 stack versions (in rancher-compose.yml) ordered by the following directories:

0) "version: custom_branch"

1) "version: stable"

2) "version: 0.3"

3) "version: 0.4"

When installing a new stack all versions are seen - which is good!

- When trying to upgrade from "custom_branch" - "custom_branch" and "stable" are seen in template versions drop down
- When trying to upgrade from "stable" - only "stable" is seen

(versions 0.3 and 0.4 are not seen during upgrade at all).

I got a feeling that Rancher is taking the following version order instead of the expected:

- "0.3"
- "0.4"
- "custom_branch"
- "stable"

Which means you cannot upgrade from custom_branch to 0.3. Are it suppose to take versions order of directory numbers?

Example of my rancher-compose.yml:

`.catalog:
  name: "NAME"
  version: "0.3"
  description: "My Stack"
  minimum_rancher_version: v1.6.10
  maximum_rancher_version: v1.6.14
  questions:
    - variable: "HOST_DOMAIN"
      description: "Domain address of the Rancher host"
      label: "Host Domain"
      required: true
      default: "example.net"
      type: "string"`

**Rancher versions:**
rancher/server: 1.6.14
rancher/agent: 1.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version strings need to be valid semver strings to be compared properly.  Using higher folder number to determine what's an upgrade doesn't work for any real-world software with more than one line of supported versions:

0: 1.0.0
1: 1.1.0 
2: 2.0.0-beta1
3: 1.0.1